# Convert 3 broadband connection to single Wifi router via a PC

Tags: wifi

I heard its possible to connect three broadband connections to a single server and then create one WiFi router out of it.
The setup I was told was:

- Three broadband connections - using 3 network cards
- Windows Server
- One wifi router card
- A specific software to convert three connections to Wifi router.

Is it possible. Could someone please explain me the details of getting it done?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be doing something called bonding. Check out this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323431) for the specifics. One term to research NLB-Network Load Balancing for Windows.